# Detect which target was compiled using precompiler macro

Tags: ios

I am using Xcode 5 and an trying to make a lite version and a paid version of my app.  I duplicated the target and set the precompiler macros to be IS_PRO =1 AND IS_LITE =1.  Then I added the following code in my App Delegate.

```
if (self.window.frame.size.height == 568)
        {
            #ifdef IS_PRO

                UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"iPhone5" bundle:nil];

                UIViewController *viewController = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"iPhone5"];

                self.window.rootViewController = viewController;
                [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

                return YES;

            #else

            UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"iPhone5 Lite" bundle:nil];

            UIViewController *viewController = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"iPhone5 Lite"];

            self.window.rootViewController = viewController;
            [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

            return YES;

            #endif

        }
        else
        {
            #ifdef IS_PRO

            UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"iPhone3.5" bundle:nil];

            UIViewController *viewController = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"iPhone3.5"];

            self.window.rootViewController = viewController;
            [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

            return YES;

            #else

            UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"iPhone3.5 Lite" bundle:nil];

            UIViewController *viewController = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"iPhone3.5 Lite"];

            self.window.rootViewController = viewController;
            [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

            return YES;

            #endif
        }
```

However, the only thing that works is the code between the #ifdef and #else.  The code between the #else and #endif is white (not multi-colored like it typically is when Xcode accepts the code).  This code works perfectly if i remove the precompiler macros and am only trying to detect the screen size.

I also did a quick unrelated test to see if I could get the following to work:

```
#ifdef IS_LITE
    NSLog(@"LITE VERSION");
#else
    NSLog(@"PRO VERSION");
#endif
```

And I get the same result.  Xcode will only read the code between the #ifdef and #else, the code between #else and #endif is white.  Can somebody please help me?!?

Comment: It's unclear what you did. Make sure you only define one of the macros in each target. The "pro" target should only define `IS_PRO` and the "lite" version should only define `IS_LITE`.

Answer (score 0):

The `#ifdef` is always true if your macro is defined. Whether its value is 0 or 1.

It will work like this:

```
#if(IS_LITE)
    NSLog(@"LITE VERSION");
#else
    NSLog(@"PRO VERSION");
#endif
```

Comment: This should be `#if(IS_LITE)`. There is no macro named `LITE_VERSION` according to the question.

Comment: Yes, it is IS_LITE , not LITE_VERSION. I had a typo in my original post.  It is corrected now. However, when I type the simple NSLog example above, Xcode only recognizes the code between the #if(IS_LITE) and #else. The code between #else and #endif is white, which leads me to believe it's not being recognized.

Comment: Well I re-duplicated the target and set up the preprocessor compiler code again and it started working for some reason…This time I did not rename the new target scheme or info.plist so maybe that had something to do with it??  Anyway, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Pre processor macros has to be defined for each target in

Target-->Build settings --> Pre processor macros.

When you build a specific target specific code will be compiled.